# Do I need to transform nominal variables to be distinct fields for sklearn random forest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

This is a sample of dataset I'm using to look at lapsed customers.  I've converted categorical values to be numbers.  However I believe that sklearn random forest will treat these fields as discrete numbers e.g. assume that customer number 4 is double that of customer number 2?  Do I need to cross-tab or vectorize these values before applying my random forest model?

Lapse_Flag,Cust,Sales,Cust Age,State,Main Sales Territory
0,1,28.46,3,1,1
0,2,46.07,3,2,1
0,3,108.48,3,3,2
1,4,265,3,4,3
0,5,54.42,3,5,4
0,6,0,1,6,3
0,7,371.93,3,7,5
1,8,35.6,3,8,6
1,9,357.95,2,9,7
0,10,5584.14,3,5,4
0,11,41207.02,3,10,4
0,12,5958.18,3,5,4
0,13,1028.14,1,11,7
0,14,446.67,2,7,5
0,15,0,3,1,1
0,16,6256,2,12,7
0,17,4618.72,3,2,1
1,18,275.58,3,12,2
1,19,1417.22,2,8,6

Answer (score 0):

I assume your customers can only be of one exact type so it's not a multi-label problem.

Then using a classifier with RandomForestClassifier() is fine to not do a regression, and sklearn deals with the multi-class.

See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) for the multi-class/multi-label documentation with an example of a similar case [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-learning).

You can also use the [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#label-encoding) you transform your data.